# Как реализовать one-hot кодирование?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имею фреймы данных `new_df` и `df_train1` соответственно:

```
      a    d
Id          
0   NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN

     target1
0  [a, b, c]
1        [a]
2     [b, d]
```

Я хотел бы пробегать по именам колонок `new_df`, смотреть есть ли это значение в элементах (списках) `df_train1` и ставить 1 или 0 вместо `NaN` на соответствующей позиции.

В результате я хотел бы получить фрейм `new_df` следующего вида, закодировав столбцы в виде one-hot векторов:

```
     a     d
Id          
0    1     0
1    1     0
2    0     1
```

На данный момент я имею следующий код с неверным выводом:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','d'])
new_df.insert(loc=0, column='Id', value=np.arange(0,3,1))
new_df = new_df.set_index('Id')
df_train1 = pd.DataFrame({'target1':[['a','b','c'],['a'],['b','d']]})

for word in new_df.columns:
  for i in new_df.index:
    if list(word) in list(df_train1.loc[df_train1.index==i,'target1']):
      new_df.at[i,word]=1
    else:
      new_df.at[i,word]=0
new_df


    a   d
Id      
0   0   0
1   1   0
2   0   0
```

Подскажите, в чем заключается ошибка?

Возможно есть более простые пути для реализации такого кодирования, или же другое, более подходящее кодирование для подобных задач с большим количеством данных? В моем реальном датасете 16290 объектов и 1264 признаков (колонок `new_df`). Этот код выполнялся 3+ часа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться специально созданным для этого классом [sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=["a", "d"])

res = pd.DataFrame(
    mlb.fit_transform(df_train1["target1"]),
    index=df_train1.index,
    columns=mlb.classes_
)
```

результат:

```
In [36]: res
Out[36]:
   a  d
0  1  0
1  1  0
2  0  1
```

Answer (score 3):

я бы предложил использовать векторизованные методы, например так:

```
tmp = pd.get_dummies(df_train1.explode('target1'), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
res = tmp.groupby(tmp.index).sum()[new_df.columns]
```

теперь res:

```
   a  d
0  1  0
1  1  0
2  0  1
```

Если по условию у вас в списках датафрейма `target1` могут быть повторы, то правильнее будет сделать так:

```
res = tmp.groupby(tmp.index).any().astype(int)[new_df.columns]
```